# Magento 2.1 - How do I downgrade Algolia Search?

Tags: magento, magento2, algolia, magento2.1

I've been using Algolia Search for Magento 2.1 for 2 weeks.
Somehow I accidentally ran the composer command and updated Algolia to version 1.10.0.
Now I want to downgrade it back to version 1.8.5.
Could you please show me how to do that?